# Multi-View ports glitch? imgui-java

Tags: java, glfw, imgui

My problem is when I try to enable multi-view port support it doesn't work. I added ViewportsEnable to my configFlags:

```
io.addConfigFlags(ImGuiConfigFlags.ViewportsEnable);
```

and I call these two function:

```
ImGui.updatePlatformWindows();
ImGui.renderPlatformWindowsDefault();
```

in my main loop.

what am I doing wrong?